# Gear change recording

Tags: gears, garmin, technology, strava, electronics

Has anyone heard of a device that records gear changes?

Like a cadence sensor or power meter, but specific to recording when you change gear.
With all the data we can currently capture about our cycle *training*, it would be interesting to see which gears are used and when, mapping this against gradient/speed/cadence/power/... .

While I don't plan on dropping any coin on di2 or etap, is this even something included in them?

Comment: If you have speed and cadence, you can work out gear changes.

Comment: If you have a way to record speed and cadence you can derive gear changes. The fourth plot [here](http://anonymous.coward.free.fr/wattage/components/components.html) shows an example.

Comment: @R Chung : I beat you by a milli second... :)

Comment: Shimano Di2 transmits gear changes via ANT+ if you add a small transmitter to the system, but still only the number of shiftings, not the ratios used.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://apps.garmin.com/en-US/apps/deb4b872-48be-409c-b91a-9b8485d2fc80 you may create your own data-field for Garmin. Personally I'd love to have one - will try one day =)

Answer (score 1):

No such product exists for mechanical groupsets yet. As for Di2, you just need the little Bluetooth transmitter to communicate with your head unit. This will record the number of shifts, as well as the gear that you're using at any time.

[I've included a screenshot of the Wahoo Elemnt app to show how this data is displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tH8sn.jpg). To set this up, you need to program your cassette and chainring ratios into the head-unit, because your Di2 isn't able to tell the number of teeth, only which cog it's on.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using an Android app called Urban Biker that displays/records ride data that includes gear changes that are very accurate by automatically calculating from speed and cadence.